# Qual è la differenza fra regalo, dono e presente?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, difference, synonym

Le parole *regalo*, *dono* e *presente* sono sinonimi, ma hanno differenze che vorrei mi fossero spiegate anche con esempi d’uso.

Comment: Hai provato a consultare un dizionario? Cosa non ti è chiaro?

Comment: Io non conosco la differenza fra dono, regalo e presente.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it show no research: a simple search on a (possibly monolingual, since the OP seem to somewhat master Italian) dictionary would solve it.

Comment: Suppongo che tu sia ancora abbastanza agli inizi del tuo apprendimento dell'italiano, ma sappi che “voglio una spiegazione...” è un modo poco cortese di esprimersi.

Comment: Benvenuto/a di nuovo su Italian.SE! Forse questa [pagina del Help Center](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) ti può aiutare a migliorare questa e altre tue domande.

Answer (score 4):

Le tre parole hanno usi simili.

Regalo è certamente il più universale e comune di tutti, si può applicare in qualunque contesto. Esempi: regalo di compleanno, regalo di natale, regalo di nozze. Si può utilizzare anche in alcuni contesti con uso figurato, ad esempio: questa giornata è stata un regalo.

Dono si utilizza meno frequentemente, ha un registro leggermente più formale e si usa prevalentemente in espressioni figurate o con significato spirituale, ad esempio: un dono di Dio, il tuo amore è un dono. Si usa altresì nell'espressioni relative a capacità di natura eccezionale, come il dono dell'ubiquità, il dono dell'eloquenza.

Presente si utilizza poco, in alcune regioni più che in altre. Oltre al bell'esempio e gioco di parole di Kung Fu Panda, nell'area da cui vengo e dove vivo presente è un regalo prevalentemente di valore limitato, simbolico, ad esempio: gli ho portato un presente per non andare a mani vuote.

Answer (score 0):

Sono sinonimi. Regalo è largamente più utilizzato degli altri, che sono spesso più poetici. Presente praticamente non si usa (almeno in Toscana), mentre dono si usa per un regalo in condizioni fuori dall'ordinario e spesso in modo figurativo. Per esempio:

- un dono ai poveri
- un dono di dio
- il dono della vita

**Fun fact** - Nella traduzione italiana di Kung Fu Panda, il maestro OOgway dice a Po:

*C'è un detto: ieri è storia, domani è un mistero, ma oggi... è un dono. Per questo si chiama presente*

Che è un gioco di parole per dire che il presente, inteso come *oggi* o *adesso*, è un dono, rimandando all'altro significato di presente.

Edit: ho aggiunto esempi con dono e Kung Fu Panda.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Invece di scrivere "etc." potresti cercare di essere un po' più esplicito/a su come si usa il sostantivo "dono" (non il verbo "donare")?

Comment: Attenzione: “figurativo” si dice soprattutto di qualcosa che rappresenta vere e proprie figure (arti figurative etc.); forse intendi “figurato” o “traslato”.

Answer (score 0):

Tutte buone le risposte già date.
Premetto che questi possono essere utilizzate in senso figurato come già detto. L'italiano è lingua che respira libertà per cui vige la licenza poetica per il senso figurato dei sinonimo.

Mi soffermo sull'uso corrente a me noto:

- regalo quando c'è un evento individuale o da calendario da festeggiare;
- presente: è quel comportamento simbolico di piccolo valore che si porta in visita a qualcuno per non presentarsi a mani vuote;
- dono: è un dare senza pretese, gratuità squisita e sincera.